# Is there any way to detect MySQL running as in Google cloud SQL or not?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am writing an application to monitor MySQL servers. I want to know whether it is a normal server or hosted MySQL server. It is possible to check whether it is hosted in Amazon(RDS/Aurora) by checking the [basedir](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-detect-MySQL-running-as-Amazon-RDS-instance/answer/Bill-Karwin) variable. Is there any way to check whether the added server is hosted in Google Cloud SQL or not using a MySQL variable or a Query?

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is running on Second Generation instance, one way would be to check for the presence of one of the [System Users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users)

> **System users**
>
> There are two system users used by Second Generation instances:
>
> `cloudsqlimport@localhost`
>
> This user is used for data imports.
>
> `cloudsqlreplica@%`
>
> This user is used as a replication user for replicas.
>
> You cannot delete or modify these users.

So you could do something like

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'cloudsqlimport'
```

if it returns something, then you can assume that you are running on google cloud